# How to remove UIView after UIGravityBehavior has moved it off screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I tried to set an block on the action property, but that didn't work... any ideas? I know the UIView animation... method has a completion block, but not sure about the UIDynamicAnimations.

EDIT: adding code

```
[self.animator removeAllBehaviors];
UIGravityBehavior *gravityBehaviour = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.onscreen]];
gravityBehaviour.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(0, 10);
gravityBehaviour.action = ^{
    if(self.onscreen.frame.origin.y > [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)
       [self.onscreen removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"locations is %f, height is %f", self.onscreen.frame.origin.y, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
};
[self.animator addBehavior:gravityBehaviour];

UIDynamicItemBehavior *itemBehaviour = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.onscreen]];
[itemBehaviour addAngularVelocity:-M_PI_2 forItem:self.onscreen];

[self.animator addBehavior:itemBehaviour];
```

The output reflected that the view just continued to be moved even while off screen.

Comment: Setting a block on the action property of the behavior is the right way to do it. Please post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it by throwing one more thing in the if statement: [animator removeAllBehaviors]; that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Might also want to look at how I do it in my book: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch04p175dynamics/Dynamics/ViewController.m

Answer (score 0):

```
let dynamicBehaviour = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [randomWord])
weak var weakBehaviour = dynamicBehaviour
weak var weakSelf = self


dynamicBehaviour.action = {

  if let currentY = weakBehaviour?.linearVelocityForItem(rndWord).y {

    if currentY > CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame) / 2 {
      weakSelf?.animator?.removeAllBehaviors()
      weakSelf?.randomWord?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
  }
}
```